# Directory Listing on WordPress

Tags: access-control, configuration

If a WorPress application that uses the Akismet wordpress plugin has certain directory listing exposed publicly, like, akismet-en_AU.po and the other .po files, and directories like plugins, themes, uploads (primarily containing just image files) etc.only accessible,
should this be considered a security flaw ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is security flaw on its own (please read below, as this statement is general and not particular to that plugin), but it does go against good practices, as no one should allow access a resource if that resource doesn't need to be exposed.

This *might* be a security problem if any of the files exposed have any kind of private data (such as configuration files with DB credentials, or API keys to call a remote service). And even something less desirable is that maybe everything is OK now, but something in your installation might change in a few months and start exposing data, so this means that you might need to re-validate your assumptions with each update.

Bottom line, try to follow good practices and do not allow access if it's not required. Plus wordpress is a very common target for attacks, which increases the risk.